# How do I see the selected k from parsnip::nearest_neighbor()

Tags: r, knn, tidymodels

If I fit a fit a *k* nearest neighbors model using `parsnip::nearest_neighbor()`, what *k* is selected if I don't specify how to tune?

I am trying to figure out what *k* is selected here:

```
the_model <- nearest_neighbor() %>%
  set_engine("kknn") %>% 
  set_mode("classification") 

the_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(the_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(the_model) 

the_results <-
  the_workflow %>%
  fit_resamples(resamples = cv_folds, 
                metrics = metric_set(roc_auc),
                control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))
```

I know that if I use `nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune())` I can get the *k* back using  `select_best("roc_auc")` but without specifying how to tune I get results but `select_best()` does not return a *k*.  What *k* value is it using (and how did you figure out the answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify parameters for a model specification in parsnip, the value will be determined by the defaults in the underlying engine implementation unless otherwise specified in the documentation.

Look at the documentation for `nearest_neighbors()` and go down to [arguments](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/nearest_neighbor.html#arguments) it says under **neighbors**

> For kknn, a value of 5 is used if neighbors is not specified.

You can also use the `translate()` function from {parsnip} to see the code that the model specification creates

```r
library(parsnip)

the_model <- nearest_neighbor() %>%
  set_engine("kknn") %>% 
  set_mode("classification") 

the_model %>%
  translate()
#> K-Nearest Neighbor Model Specification (classification)
#> 
#> Computational engine: kknn 
#> 
#> Model fit template:
#> kknn::train.kknn(formula = missing_arg(), data = missing_arg(), 
#>     ks = min_rows(5, data, 5))
```

Where we see that `ks` was set to `min_rows(5, data, 5)`, and if we specify `neighbors` in `nearest_neighbors()` that value will change

```r
nearest_neighbor(neighbors = 25) %>%
  set_engine("kknn") %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  translate()
#> K-Nearest Neighbor Model Specification (classification)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   neighbors = 25
#> 
#> Computational engine: kknn 
#> 
#> Model fit template:
#> kknn::train.kknn(formula = missing_arg(), data = missing_arg(), 
#>     ks = min_rows(25, data, 5))
```

Comment: Oh that is painful.  The vignette begins by saying nearest_neighbor(
  mode = "unknown",
  neighbors = NULL,
  weight_func = NULL,
  dist_power = NULL
) and I didn't notice the actual argument documentation.  Thank you